# Data fetch from server

Tags: java, android, http

I have been developing an application for the Android for an organization but a problem has arisen.  While my knowledge of programming is relatively fair, my use of Java has been more recent.  Which is the largest part of my current issue, being that I need to know how to set up an application to fetch data from a server.  The closest example would be a form of "news" applications that are currently available.  Where you open the application, then it updates the currently available articles or audio.  I have almost no knowledge of how to create or implement the necessary code to perform such a data fetch.  Nor do I have the knowledge of what needs to be done server side to allow the application to fetch the relevant data.  (Once again, this would be text articles and audio files)  I have come to this forums to ask for help regarding my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your server has to reply in a format that yout client can understand. You can reply in plain text, XML or JSON for example. You can implement your server as any other website, but you can keep it very minimal and reply with plain text instead of HTML.

Then you implement your client so it can understand the format you use. And you can send and receive your messages using the HttpClient.

You can use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) to manage JSON in your Java client on the Android phone. There is a tutorial about using [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) that can be useful. And finally there is an interesting talk about [Android REST client applications](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) on Youtube by Google.

Comment: First off, thank you for your expedient reply.  While you did answer one of my questions of possible formats to use server-side.  I am still unable to move forward client side.  As I just don't know how to enable the client to fetch the data and implement it straight into the UI to be read.  Thank you, and I ask that you continue to offer any further assistance that you may have.

Comment: @Programmer: I have updated my answer and added a few links that can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Rails for backend.  You can create a simple rails app with a database, and rails comes with default REST interface( meaning it would be easy to retrieve a record from the database using a url.).  Once you have this setup, you can just call the url from your android app, varying the necessary parameters.  Rails also takes care of replying the data in JSON or XML format(without additional coding), which makes it easier for you to parse in the Android App.

If you are new to Rails, the above simple setup(database and fetch using URL) will hardly take half a day.

Answer (score -2):

Why Java? With the HTML5 functionality currently available you've got a full relational database, offline/online web integration. And a sensible language for building user interfaces!

Serverside.....anything you want. I find Java a PITA to work with for web-based applications (mostly use PHP) but there's also Ruby, Perl and others. Certainlyyou're going to need some smarts there to work out what content needs to be pushed to the client.

While there are no end of open-source CMS's available, I'm not aware of any designed to run in an offline client - there's a whole new business model to explore!