# Introduction or Tutorial to fetching data from own website?

Tags: android

I need to implement a module in my Android application that fetches some textual content (not to be displayed on browser, but to be processed by the app) from my own website.

That textual content will be stored in a database (MySQL?).

My only problem is that I have never done anything like this before (although I am familiar with basic SQL), so I am not sure what would be a good methodical approach to tackle this subject, and I don't even know where to start.

Should I create a MySQL database from scratch and start coding PHP around it?

Is there a framework or wrapper that is already oriented towards communicating with Android applications and lets me focus on the idiosyncrasies of my needs?

What would you recommend as a good starting point?

Comment: Closed??? Why? At least 4 people found this question easy to answer, and they did answer it very well, and in a very helpful manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in many ways, you could do something really simple, but as you progress and begin to send more information from your servers to your apps you need to implement something more robust.

While @Robert answer is valid, I believe that for mobile phone it is much better to use RESTful webservices using JSON.

You can program your webservices in what ever you want, I would recomend (if you can do server side programming in java) to take a look at [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which is a great library to use JSON. By using JSON Objects you can transform all the information you need into a string, and then have the mobile phone convert it to a Java Object. You can the do whatever you want with that, wether its to show it in the UI or to store it in a DataBase.

- [Restful webservices](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html)

Comment: Thank you for incredible answer.

Answer (score 6):

First, you must develop a point of contact (WebService, REST service or whatever fits your needs) for your application. In my case, I'm using a PHP script that generates a JSON response.

Here is a simple PHP script that connects to a database and output a JSON ([json_encode method](http://ca.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php)) response :

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpassword", "database");

$response = array();

$pass = mysqli_query("select * from table");

while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($pass))
{
    array_push($response, array(
        "my_field"  =>  $data->my_field
    ));
}

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($link);
```

?>

The script will output a JSON response like this :

```
[{"my_field":1}]
```

When your application will request the data, via an HTTP POST or GET response, you'll parse the answer using a library. Since I'm using JSON on the PHP side, I'm currently using [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for my projects.

To request the JSON data from your Android Application, you can use a RestClass I took somewhere (can't remember), but here is the code :

```
public class RestClient
{
    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> params;
    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;
    private String url;
    private int responseCode;
    private String message;
    private String response;    

public enum RequestMethod
{
        GET,
        POST
}

public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public String getErrorMessage() {
    return message;
}

public int getResponseCode() {
    return responseCode;
}

public RestClient(String url)
{
    this.url    = url;
    params      = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    headers         = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
// Various methods.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Add a parameter to the request (pair, name/value).
 * @param name  Name of the parameter (ex: &name=)
 * @param value Value of the parameter (ex: &name=value).
 */
public void AddParam(String name, String value)
{
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

/**
 * Add a header to the request (if needed).
 * @param name  Name of the header. (ex: Content-Type)
 * @param value Value of the header. (ex: Content-Type = text/html).
 */
public void AddHeader(String name, String value)
{
    headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
/**
 * Fetch the HTTP content via POST or GET.
 * @param method            Method to be used.
 * @throws Exception        Exception to be catched in case of a network problem.
 */
public void Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
{
    switch(method) {
        case GET:
        {
            //add parameters
            String combinedParams = "";
            if(!params.isEmpty()){
                combinedParams += "?";
                for(NameValuePair p : params)
                {
                    String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");
                    if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                    {
                        combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        combinedParams += paramString;
                    }
                }
            }

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);

            //add headers
            for(NameValuePair h : headers)
            {
                request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
            }

            executeRequest(request, url);
            break;
        }
        case POST:
        {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

            //add headers
            for(NameValuePair h : headers)
            {
                request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
            }

            if(!params.isEmpty()){
                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
            }

            executeRequest(request, url);
            break;
        }
    }
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
/**
 * Alternative method to execute the HTTP request.
 * @param request   The HTTP request object to be used.
 * @param url       HTTP url.
 */
private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse httpResponse;

    try {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {

            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            response = convertStreamToString(instream);

            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
/**
 * Private method. Convert an HTTP stream to a string stream.
 * @param is        InputStream to be converted.
 * @return      String to be used.
 */
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Then on your Android app, you can instantiate the RestClient class like this (you can even add POST or GET parameter to the query):

```
RestClient c = new RestClient("http://www.myserver.com/json.php");  
c.AddParam("my_field_value", 1);

try
{
    c.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);

    // Here you can parse the JSON with an instance of Gson class.
    Gson jsonObject = new Gson();
    String jsonOutput = jsonObject.toJson(c.getResponse());

            // Do whatever you need with the data.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And voilà! You can consume JSON data, created with a PHP script from your Android application. Don't forget to add android.permission.INTERNET to your AndroidManifest.xml. Otherwise, your application will not be able to communicate with your PHP script.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer. I intend to start with the introduction to Restful webservices (never heard this term before), and then delve into actual code. This is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Feel free to comment or ask other questions. We are to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Does this tutorial help? [Connecting to MySQL database](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently calling a .Net web service to retrieve my information.  I called the web service using KSoap2 from my android application.  In searching around I couldn't find any framework to make it easier.  In the end it's actually turned out to be pretty easy.  Here is a starting point for you:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data

Comment: Thanks. In the meanwhile I found this [incredible resource](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4349733/725417). [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794801/android-server-data-fetch) is also helpful.

Comment: @uTubeFan thanks for sharing.  I'll have to take a look at those.